# Custom date range filter with third party service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble filtering some data using input provided by a user. What I'm trying to do is get a start date and an end date from a user and then return weather data from a third party service for the selected time period. Right now my plan is to have a button the user can click and then a modal will drop down with the weather data. Since these are two different views I seem to be having trouble using the model on the reservation view to filter the data on the weather view. I tried building a custom filter but I was not able to get anything to work.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Weather View

```
    <div class="modal-header">
 <h3 class="modal-title">Average Weather Temps</h3>

</div>

<div class="modal-body" ng-controller="weatherCtrl">
    <div ng-init="weather = (day | ascendingSort)" ng-repeat="weat in weather">
        {{weat.averageTemp}}
        {{weat.skyCondition}}
        {{weat.chanceOfPrecip}}
        {{weat.day | relativedate}}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
</div>
```

Inputs from reservation view

```
 <div ng-controller="DatepickerCtrl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="reservation.dateIn"  is-open="popup1.opened" show-button-bar="false" placeholder="Enter Start Date" name="startDate" id="startDate" ng-required="true"/>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
                </p>
                <div class="message" ng-show="bookingForm.startDate.$touched && bookingForm.startDate.$invalid" class="message">Start Date Required</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="reservation.dateOut" is-open="popup2.opened"  show-button-bar="false" min-date="minDate" placeholder="Enter End Date" name="endDate" id="endDate" ng-required="true"/>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <div class="message" ng-show="bookingForm.endDate.$touched && bookingForm.endDate.$invalid" class="message">End Date Required</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Weather controller and factory

```
app.factory('getWeather',  function($resource){
return $resource('http://localhost:3000/api/weather')
});

app.controller('weatherCtrl', function ($scope, getWeather) {
$scope.weather = getWeather.query();
});
```

sample JSON from web service

```
 {
    "averageTemp": 0,
    "chanceOfPrecip": "0.1849",
    "skyCondition": "sunny",
    "month": 11,
    "day": 362
},
{
    "averageTemp": 3,
    "chanceOfPrecip": "0.7055",
    "skyCondition": "sunny",
    "month": 11,
    "day": 363
},
{
    "averageTemp": 26,
    "chanceOfPrecip": "0.3572",
    "skyCondition": "sunny",
    "month": 11,
    "day": 364
},
```

Comment: where is the code for the filter you tried?

Comment: This is what i'm trying to implement for this issue.

Comment: right, but you aren't showing the code for the filter, so how is anyone supposed to help you figure out what's wrong with it?  "I was not able to get anything to work" isn't a question, it's a statement, and it doesn't explain if you tried one thing and gave up or tried hundreds of things, so aside from writing a filter for you (not what this site is about), the best anyone can do is **try to guess at your problem**.

Comment: I mean, you clearly are getting `bookingForm.startDate` and `bookingForm.endDate`, but you aren't showing where you are using these to do anything.